# String manipulation to URI in C#

Tags: c#, string, uri

I'm writing an parser for iTunes XML file and I'm trying to parse the file location to permit to the application to recover the folder.jpg from de folder.

I'm creating an URI from the location of itunes.xml in this format:

```
\\localhost\C:\MP3 Collection\Álbuns\# - E\A\a-ha\[1985] Hunting High And Low\01. Take On Me.mp3
```

I need to extract the `01. Take On Me.mp3` substring and replace it with `folder.jpg`.

Remember that this string is different in each file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Path.GetDirectoryName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) and the [Path.Combine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

```
var s = @"\\localhost\C:\MP3 Collection\Álbuns\# - E\A\a-ha\[1985] Hunting High And Low\01. Take On Me.mp3";

var result = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(s), "folder.jpg");
// result == @"\\localhost\C:\MP3 Collection\Álbuns\# - E\A\a-ha\[1985] Hunting High And Low\folder.jpg"
```